# matching regex pattern for different cards

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I have 4 different regex pattern matchers and corresponding replace strings. Inside my java code, I check for each regex and replace with the value. Is there anyway I can consolidate in single regex and single replace string?

```
DISC_CARD=(\\W|000)(6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{8})([0-9]{4}\\D)
MAST_CARD=(\\W|000)((?:5[0-9]{3}|2[2-7][0-9]{2})[0-9]{8})([0-9]{4}\\D)    
VISA_CARD=(\\W|000)(4[0-9]{11})([0-9]{4}\\D)
AMEX_CARD=(\\W|000)(3[47][0-9]{9})([0-9]{4}\\D)

DISC_MASK=$1XXXXXXXXXXXX$3
MAST_MASK=$1XXXXXXXXXXXX$3
VISA_MASK=$1XXXXXXXXXXXX$3
AMEX_MASK=$1XXXXXXXXXXX$3
```

Java code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < regPatterns.size(); i++) {
  message = regPatterns.get(i).matcher(message).replaceAll(maskPatterns[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [**alternation**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to combine all your **given** regex. Something like:

```
^(\W|000)((?<Disc>6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{8})|(?<Mast>(?:5[0-9]{3}|2[2-7][0-9]{2})[0-9]{8})|(?<Visa>4[0-9]{11})|(?<Amex>3[47][0-9]{9}))([0-9]{4}\D)$
```

**Breaking down the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of the line respectively.
- **`(\W|000)`** - Represents your first capturing group.
- **`(?<Disc>(6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{8})`** - Represents your DISC_Card validation regex.
- **`|`** - Represents alternation.
- **`(?<Mast>(?:5[0-9]{3}|2[2-7][0-9]{2})[0-9]{8})`** - Represents your MAST_CARD validation regex group.
- **`(?<Visa>4[0-9]{11})`** - Represents your VISA_CARD validation regex group.
- **`(?<Amex>3[47][0-9]{9}))`** - Represents your AMEX_CARD validation regex group.
- **`([0-9]{4}\D)`** - Represents your 3rd capturing group.(But as per new regex it is **7th capturing group**.)
- **NOTE:** I used [**named capturing group**](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#namedgroups) in order to differentiate between them and to make them more legible.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/aUcAtb/4)

**Sample Implementation in java:(Please do implement the code according to your requirement.)**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main{
    // Regex pattern
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\W|000)((?<Disc>6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{8})|(?<Mast>(?:5[0-9]{3}|2[2-7][0-9]{2})[0-9]{8})|(?<Visa>4[0-9]{11})|(?<Amex>3[47][0-9]{9}))([0-9]{4}\\D)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    // final array of strings to replace(First element for all the three and second element for the last one i.e. Amex Card)
    private static final String[] replacementStrings = {"$1xxxxxxxxxxxx$7", "$1xxxxxxxxxxx$7"};
   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Input String
        String str = "0006011123456781114D\n000341234567891234D\n0002421123456787891D\n0004123456789012346R\nTHisWOntMAtch";
        for(String st : str.split("\n")){
            System.out.println(getMaskedCardDetail(st));
        }
    }
    // Utility Method for provide Masking of card details.
    private static String getMaskedCardDetail(String givenString){
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(givenString);
        if(matcher.matches()){
            String temp = "";
            if(matcher.group("Disc") != null || matcher.group("Mast") != null || matcher.group("Visa") != null) 
                temp = matcher.replaceAll(replacementStrings[0]);
            else 
                temp = matcher.replaceAll(replacementStrings[1]);
            return temp;    
        }else{
            return "NO MATCH";
        }
    }
}
/*
Output: 
000xxxxxxxxxxxx1114D                                                                                                                          
000xxxxxxxxxxx1234D                                                                                                                           
000xxxxxxxxxxxx7891D                                                                                                                          
000xxxxxxxxxxxx2346R                                                                                                                          
NO MATCH
*/
```

You can find the sample run result of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/BJx6ATPAL)

Comment: What about the variable replacement?

Comment: Right. The Amex one is shorter.

Comment: @shmosel; The logic is we could match on the basis of named groups and choose the replacement string accordingly. Like `amexReplacementString`, `visaReplacementString`and so on. I'll post the whole implementation in a moment.

Comment: If i try this card number "6011016011016011", it didn't match. Any thoughts?

Comment: @skumar; do you want it should match? If that is the case then remove \W from your group 1 or use any non-word character before it. i.e. `(000|) `. Or the other thing that you can do is to remove the start and end delimiters. i.e. `^ and $`.

Comment: I will give a try and let you know. Thanks for these details

Comment: Nice! @skumar - If the solution worked for you, do not forget to accept the answer so that future visitors can also use the solution confidently.